# Delete all S3 buckets with Fog

Tags: amazon-s3, fog

Folks, I want to figure out how to delete all the S3 buckets with Fog without doing a list. I wont be knowing the list of buckets and objects in S3 for an account, and doing a list and then deleting sounds too expensive, isnt there a way to delete all the objects and buckets for an amazon account.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The `fog` gem does not support deleting a bucket without deleting its objects first. Unfortunately, you will have to get the object keys (by listing them first), delete the objects (I recommend using the [Delete Multiple Objects](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html) call), and then deleting the buckets themselves.

Unfortunately, Amazon S3 does not support deleting a bucket that is not empty. Whichever framework/library that you find that has this feature is executing a delete on the objects under the covers before deleting the bucket.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response, the Delete Multiple objects call is very handy, one more question, can I get the list of "buckets" in S3 for an account, I have a use case where I will not know the bucket names present in a top level account

Comment: Definitely. You can use the [GET Service](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTServiceGET.html) call: `The GET operation on the Service endpoint (s3.amazonaws.com) returns a list of all of the buckets owned by the authenticated sender of the request.`

Comment: Remember if you have version objects in the bucket then you have to delete version objects also before deleting the bucket. Bucket will not delete if your Bucket list showing empty bucket but that bucket has version objects.
Version objects exist only if s3 versioning was enabled on the bucket.
So
1. List All Object of the Bucket and Delete all if Exist
2. List All Version Objects of the Bucket and Delete All if Exist
3. Delete Bucket